How can i check the properties inside an object accessed by it's own function?
I'm trying out things to understand how it works.. not sure how would i be able to get the ID for example?
const opciones = [{
        id: 0,
        texto: "Inicio",
        descripcionTitulo: "Bienvenido al programa de carga de Viajes",
        descripcion: "Selecciona lo que quieras hacer",
        icon: <FaCheckCircle />,
        next: function next() {
                console.log(this.id)
        },
        contenido: <Inicio setToggle={setToggle} />,
        botonSiguiente: "Nuevo Viaje"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        texto: "Descripción",
        descripcionTitulo: "Descripcion",
        descripcion: "detalles importantes",
        icon: <FaBookOpen />,
        next: function next() {

        },
        contenido: <Descripcion setToggle={setToggle} />,
        botonSiguiente: "Siguiente"

    }
    ]

i have a function inside my object and i'm trying to log it's ID inside it's own function if it makes sense.. i'm not sure how do I access it?
I'm getting undefined onclick if i try to log "this.id"

How are you invoking the function?

Check the console of this example I have created!

I'm mapping over the object and was calling it with onClick directly instead of using an anonymous function like so:
onClick={() => opcion.next(opcion)}
finally fixed it!!
Sorry kinda new to all this lol

To get the id of each one of your entries you would have to do this:
First of all, one easy way to get each id would be to loop through your opciones object and log what the property next gives you.
I am attaching you a reproducible example for you to understand what I mean.
It is pretty easy. You don't have to do anything except iterating through your object and console.log(id) the id you have already assigned with your so-called function next().
That's all you need to do.


const opciones = [
  {
id: 0,
texto: "Inicio",
descripcionTitulo: "Bienvenido al programa de carga de Viajes",
descripcion: "Selecciona lo que quieras hacer",
icon: "",
next: function next() {
  return "The id you are looking for is: " + this.id;
},
contenido: "",
botonSiguiente: "Nuevo Viaje",
  },
  {
id: 1,
texto: "Descripción",
descripcionTitulo: "Descripcion",
descripcion: "detalles importantes",
icon: "",
next: function next() {
  return "The id you are looking for is: " + this.id;
},
contenido: "",
botonSiguiente: "Siguiente",
  },
];

let id = null;
// iterate through every option
for(var i = 0; i < opciones.length; i++){
  id = opciones[i].next();
  console.log(id);
}



